# How to get device movement with CoreMotion in swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, accelerometer, gyroscope, core-motion

I wanna get the device displacement in centimeters or milimeters or whatever distance unit. But I dont know how to achieve this. I've done some research and i can now get acceleromation and gyro data. But there was no success in turning it into useful data. It has lots of unneccessary tiny changes. 
One of the biggest problems is that when I use `userAcceleration.x` and move the device right, it will first get some negative numbers then it goes positive. How can I fix this?

Comment: Device displacement is impossible. Remember your basic physics. Acceleration is zero when displacement changes at a constant rate (in a particular inertial reference frame).

Comment: @BaseZen i just want something similar to this. Do you know some hack or what?

Comment: It isn't a question of hacking; it's about learning signal processing. Since the input (your hand) has a lot of jitter, and you're dealing with a very sensitive sensor, you need to use some kind of smoothing function. Look into moving averages of the samples, both simple and exponential. But your question as a whole doesn't really have an answer.

Comment: @BaseZen can you explain more about the smoothing function? I dont have good knowledge about physics

Comment: Keep an array that contains the last 5 samples. Each new sample pushes out the oldest one. Use the average of the 5 most recent samples as your signal. That's a simple moving average. Changes will be smoothed out since it will take several values in a particular direction to create a substantial trend.

Comment: @BaseZen Thank you very much. BaseZen